# Counting strings in single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of transaction IDs where one column is made of different tags. Each row can have one *or* multiple tags. I want to count the instances of *each* tag. Using df.col.value_counts() won't work in this case because it won't count single occurrences.

| Transaction | Tag |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | tag1 |
| 02 | tag1, tag3 |
| 03 | tag2 |
| 04 | tag2, tag3 |

Using .value_counts() would result in:

- tag1 **1**
- tag1, tag3 **1**
- tag2 **1**
- tag2, tag3 **1**

What I am looking for is instead:

- tag1 **2**
- tag2 **2**
- tag3 **2**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) before [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) :

```
df['Tag'].str.split(', *').explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
Tag
tag1    2
tag3    2
tag2    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Or without pandas, using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

out = Counter(tag for s in df['Tag'] for tag in s.split(', '))
```

Output: `Counter({'tag1': 2, 'tag3': 2, 'tag2': 2})`